# Why does it take so long for an app update to reach the Ubuntu repositories?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Take `LibreOffice` for example. Version 3.6.0 has been out for [quite some time now](http://www.libreoffice.org/download/), but `Ubuntu` users are still waiting for version 3.5.4.2 to update (I'm not the only one, right?)